# In WPF how to define a Data template in case of enum?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, enums

I have a Enum defined as Type

```
public Enum **Type**
{
   OneType,
   TwoType,
   ThreeType
};
```

Now I bind **Type** to a drop down Ribbon Control Drop Down Menu in a Ribbon Control that displays each menu with a MenuName with corresponding Image.

( I am using Syncfusion Ribbon Control ).

I want that each enum type like ( OneType ) has data template defined that has Name of the menu and corrospending image.

How can I define the data template of enum ?

Please suggest me the solution,  if this is possible !!

Please also tell me if its not possible or I am thinking in the wrong direction !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx), and assign it to the [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx) property of the menu. In the code of the `DataTemplateSelector`, you just need to return a `DataTemplate` based on the enum value

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the reply. I have seen the DataTemplateSelector and ItemTemplateSelector links and it seem to me that its possible.Just to ask you if you have tried this similar thing , it will be great if you can provide me the snippets of that!!

Comment: there's an example on the MSDN page

Answer (score 17):

Not sure whether this is an applicable solution to your particular situation, but it is relevant to the question of DataTemplate for enum. It is possible to create one DataTemplate for the enum type and use DataTriggers to tweak the controls in that template for individual enum value:

Enum:

```
enum MyEnumType 
{
    ValueOne,
    ValueTwo,
}
```

Template:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyEnumType}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="valueText"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static MyEnumType.ValueOne}">
            <Setter TargetName="valueText" Property="Text" Value="First Value" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static MyEnumType.ValueTwo}">
            <Setter TargetName="valueText" Property="Text" Value="Second Value" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very often the case that people use enums when they should be using polymorphism.  You should, at the least, check to see if this is one of those cases.  The presence of `switch` blocks in your class's code that check the value of the instance's enum is often a sign that this is a good idea.  If you can eliminate the enum by defining subclasses, then you don't have to mess around with the likes of data template selectors and value converters.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: Xaml code tends to bloat sometimes, but it might be a good practice to keep that kind of logic out of your "main" business logic. All depending on how other data in the application is handled, it might be a good war to "mess around with the likes of data template selectors and value converters", to write solid unit tests for these very specific units and to keep the rest of your code clean of that UI logic :)