# WPF Custom DataTemplateSelector based on Enum property in Custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I've just learnt about creating custom UserControls and I am now learning about DataTemplates, still learning about the properties though so I can imagine that the implementation of the control property is wrong.

I've had a go at creating a UserControl called `ExtendedListBox` which can display its items with a checkbox or a normal listbox. Below is the implementation of the `ExtendedListBox` The property `DisplayAs` is used for picking which DataTemplate to use.

I've had a look at quite a few questions relating to DataTemplateSelectors here on StackOverflow and it now has me questioning this implementation, should this be done by ContentControl? (See: [Bind a property to DataTemplateSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011005/bind-a-property-to-datatemplateselector))

```
public partial class ExtendedListBox : UserControl
{
    public ExtendedListBoxDisplay DisplayAs { get; set; }

    public ExtendedListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml for the user control the DataTemplates are in the UserControl Resources as CheckedListBoxTemplate and ListBoxTemplate

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTest.Configuration.Controls.ExtendedListBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:enums="clr-UserControlTest.Configuration.Enums"
             xmlns:local="clr-UserControlTest.Configuration.Controls"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:templateSelectors="clr-namespace:UserControlTest.Configuration.Controls.TemplateSelectors"
             x:Name="UcExtendedListBox"
             d:DesignHeight="84"
             d:DesignWidth="100"
             SizeChanged="ResizeControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckedListBoxTemplate" DataType="enums:ExtendedListBoxDisplay">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate" DataType="enums:ExtendedListBoxDisplay">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListBox x:Name="LstItems"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                             ElementName=UcExtendedListBox}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             SelectionChanged="RaiseSelectionChanged">
                    <ItemsControl>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
                <templateSelectors:ExtendedListBoxDataTemplateSelector 
                        CheckedListBoxTemplate="{StaticResource CheckedListBoxTemplate}"
                        ListBoxTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}" />
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

This is the DataTemplateSelector its implementation is rather simple.

```
public class ExtendedListBoxDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CheckedListBoxTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ListBoxTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        var data = (ExtendedListBoxDisplay)item;

        switch (data)
        {
            case ExtendedListBoxDisplay.CheckedListBox:
                return CheckedListBoxTemplate;
            case ExtendedListBoxDisplay.ListBox:
                return ListBoxTemplate;
            default:
                return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        }
    }
}
```

So I've gone to run this and it doesn't work, I'm guessing that its because I haven't binded the items and the property to look for? Would any please be able to guide me in the correct direction as a first time user of DataTemplateSelectors?

Many thanks.

Comment: What items are you binding to the `ListBox`?  What are you using `DisplayAs` for?

Comment: Good question, I havn't used binding yet so I just populate these with a random list of objects - been trying to keep it generic, but looking about it doesn't look as if that can be done?, DisplayAs is supposed to be used for setting which DataTemplate is ment to be used in the ListBox

Comment: Well DataTemplates work based on the type of the item that is bound, so the target type of the DataTemplate needs to match the type of the items bound to the ListBox.  In this case you would probably be better off using a ControlTemplate, as you don't seem to care much about the data type that is bound to the ListBox.

Comment: Alternatively, you should drop the target type of the DataTemplate, since it will actually work against you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` to an `IEnumerable<ExtendedListBoxDisplay>` (or an `IEnumerable<YourDataObject>` actually):

```
public partial class ExtendedListBox : UserControl
{
    public ExtendedListBoxDisplay DisplayAs { get; set; }

    public ExtendedListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LstItems.ItemsSource = new List<ExtendedListBoxDisplay>() { new ExtendedListBoxDisplay() };
    }
}
```

The `SelectTemplate` method of the `ExtendedListBoxDataTemplateSelector` class will be called once per item in the `ItemsSource` collection and the `DataTemplate` that you return will be applied to this item.

The `object` parameter that gets passed to the method is a reference to the  corresponding item in the `ItemsSource`.

Note that if `ExtendedListBoxDisplay` is actually an enum, you should probably modify your `SelectTemplate` method and set the `ItemsSource` to another type.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you have to set enum value to dataTemplate. Hope this link helps, it provide some insight how to do it.
[DataTemplate in case of Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441901/in-wpf-how-to-define-a-data-template-in-case-of-enum)
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you specify the `DataType` of a `DataTemplate` you are saying that template should only be applied to items of that type (or derived from that type).
So the first thing you need to do is remove the `DataType="enums:ExtendedListBoxDisplay"` from both of your templates.

Next, you need to modify the template selector to use the DependancyObject that is being bound instead of the data itself, since you don't really care what data type the items are.

E.g:

```
public class ExtendedListBoxDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CheckedListBoxTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ListBoxTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (container == null || !(container is ExtendedListBox))
        {
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        var listBox = (ExtendedListBox)container;

        switch (listBox.DisplayAs)
        {
            case ExtendedListBoxDisplay.CheckedListBox:
                return CheckedListBoxTemplate;
            case ExtendedListBoxDisplay.ListBox:
                return ListBoxTemplate;
            default:
                return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

        }
    }
}
```

So now, rather then expecting the item to be an ExtendedListBoxDisplay enum, we are now expecting the container to be an `ExtendedListBox`.  Then we check the DisplayAs property of the `ExtendedListBox` and use that to determine which template to show.